# Enterprise library 6 menu does not show all blocks

Tags: visual-studio-2015, enterprise-library

[Enterprise Library console screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0uJV.png)
Hi
I am using Visual studio 2015 community edition and have installed Enterprise library 6. Installer was downloaded from some website and exe is Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ConfigConsoleV6.2015.exe

As shown in above pic, I cannot see application blocks like logging etc. in block menu. How can I add these blocks?